# What will happen if we rub an insulator and conductor?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, conductors, insulators

What will happen if we rub a neutral conductor with a neutral insulator? Will they get charged or remain neutral?

Comment: Best to do the experiment yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The conductor may be charged by the rubbing. The metals are sometimes included in the triboelectric series, like in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect#Triboelectric_series). If you rub the metal disk of an electroscope with wool, the leaves will spread apart when removing the wool, due to the charge on the disk. The disk should not be connected to earth, of course.

Comment: So if I rub a metal comb on my hair while wearing rubber gloves will the comb get charged?

Comment: Yes, theoretically. In practice, however, there are a few problems. In the context of electrostatics, latex household gloves are electrically conductive, hair is conductive if the air is not very dry, and the comb has pointed teeth where the charge leaks away by corona discharge, and by touching your skin.

Comment: In case of rubbing, if I rub the conductor with an insulator , if conductor gains electrons they will easily flow in positively charged insulator. But can't conductor also pull the extra electron residing on the surface of insulator? So how are they getting charged?

Comment: The two materials that are rubbed together have different electron affinities. Electron affinitity is a property of materials. The one with the highest electron affinity takes some of the electrons of the other one. If you want to delve deeper you'll need quantum physics.

Comment: So only electron affinity matters but not conductor or insulator while transfer of charges?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not really that simple. Metal-to-insulator rubbing is much less predictable and repeatable than insulator-to-insulator rubbing. See this [Alphalab page](https://www.alphalabinc.com/triboelectric-series/).